# Understand how dionaea honeypot emulated services work

Tags: ids, honeypot

I'm trying to understand Dionaea honeypot and the information flow. 
    I understand that it emulates some services, like SMB, ftp, tftp, try to 
    responde with these, then gets the shellcode and analyzes it with libemu.
    My question is how emulated services works, and how can be exploited. 
  Ok, let's say that the attacker will use an ftp vulnerability. What will he send? 
What are the responeses of honeypot? 
At what OSI level are all happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At OSI lvl. 3 it is captured AND handled lvl 4-7 in a sandboxes, that are making the analysis and emulation in secured environment.

UPDATE: In case of FTP, it listens for a packets coming to FTP port, captures them, after that *libemu* takes its part and the process begins : it creates layer7-to-layer4 "thing" that acts like a FTP server. The "thing" is actually a *honeypot* - it replies as ordered, giving an attacker feeling that there's some information that can be stolen or a shell code can be executed - the sweets for a hacker, or *the honey*. Of course it is just a scripted trap, that can record everything the attacker does/attempts to do.

Comment: i ask for a **packets sequence** in a scenario let's say ftp

Comment: @MSD561 I updated my answer. Do you need more info?

Comment: Yes i need more info please. Where exactly in this flow appear vulnerability in FTP? What is exactly a vulnerability in this process and how the honeypot respond to that?

Comment: @MSD561 the flow in **this honeypot implementation** appears at the shell script/injection on OSI layer 5-7, guarded&monitored by libemu.This particular implementation is not proficient in *packet exploiting detection*, so [SnortInline](http://snort-inline.sourceforge.net/oldhome.html) or something similar is strongly recommended, but in observation mode only.The vulnerability **is** a possibility(actually - the *illusion* of possibility) to inject and execute a custom shell code.The honeypot has it's response limits due to security sandboxing and responds basically - in this implementation.